# How to clone an object in a React state without referencing it

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React state that has some objects in it.
I want to be able to clone the `c: "value"`, in the initial state, before it gets overwritten by `e.target.value` input value

The reason why im doing this is because I want to this stored value to be tha actual value if user leaves the input empty

```
StateObj = {
 a: "one",
 b: 2,
 option: {
  c: "value"
 }
}
```

```
<InputComp 
 value={StateObj.option.c}
 onBlur={(e) => {
  if(e.target.value === ""){
    props.onChange(["option", "c"], "cloned value")} //the initial value c: "value"
   }
 }}
 onChange={(e) => props.onChange(["option", "c"], e.target.value)} //gets overwritten if user start typing
>
```

Comment: What do you mean by reset the input, wouldn't it already be empty?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I meant to reset it back to that cloned c value

Comment: For avoid referencing, I usually used spread syntax, "..." expression.

Comment: I did & the value still changes when u type on the input, I want this value to only get that initial value and prevent it from changing when the state changes.

Comment: @HumanoidMk.12 he has nested objects and `...` does not deep copy. In a handful of cases you are right though. You would need to do something like this to perform a deep copy `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(StateObj.option))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Follow up to my comment on the OP.

Here is an example:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

function YourComponent(props) {
  const [stateObj, setStateObj] = useState({
    a: "one",
    b: 2,
    option: {
      c: "value",
    },
  });

  const originalOption = useRef(null); // this will hold the original option object

  useEffect(() => {
    // On mount, store the initial value of the option object
    originalOption.current = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(stateObj.option));
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (path, value) => {
    // your existing logic here to change the value
    if(value === '') {
      // if the input is emptied, reset the option object
      setStateObj(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        option: originalOption.current
      }));
    } else {
      // if there's a value, update the state normally
      // your logic here
    }
  };

  return (
    <InputComp
      value={stateObj.option.c}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(["option", "c"], e.target.value)}
    />
  );
}
```

### I highly suggest reviewing this post as well.

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: totally forgot about useRef in this situation, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

To clone an object without referencing it, you can use the spread operator (`...`) or the `Object.assign()` method to create a shallow copy of the object. This way, any changes made to the cloned object won't affect the original one. Here's how you can achieve this in your React component:

**Using the spread operator:**

```
const clonedOption = { ...StateObj.option };

// Pass the cloned option to the InputComp
<InputComp 
  value={clonedOption.c}
  onChange={(e) => props.onChange(["option", "c"], e.target.value)}
>
```

**Using Object.assign():**

```
const clonedOption = Object.assign({}, StateObj.option);

// Pass the cloned option to the InputComp
<InputComp 
  value={clonedOption.c}
  onChange={(e) => props.onChange(["option", "c"], e.target.value)}
>
```

Both of these methods will create a new object, `clonedOption`, which is a shallow copy of `StateObj.option`. Changes made to `clonedOption` won't be reflected in the original object `StateObj.option`.

This way, you can safely use the `clonedOption` as the value for your input field, and when the user leaves the input empty, you can reset the input to the original value if needed.

Comment: both the Object.assing nor the spread ... didnt work for me, it seems like value is still somehow referecing the state, but the assigning state to a useRef in a useEffect worked for me